# Huge CPU load - php-fpm + nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I use php-fpm with STATIC pools and the problem is that 2-3 pools from 20 are used with 80-100% CPU. Other php pools stay unused.

My question is: **Why other 17 processes stay unused?**

We used AWS instance c4.large.
Our docker image use 1024 Units of CPU and  2560 MB ram.

[DOCKER containers in instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBgTp.png)

[ALL PROCESSES in container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LepSj.png)

[TOP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLGBD.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: More of a question for http://superuser.com/ IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP-FPM pm static setting depends heavily on how much free memory your server has. Basically if you are suffering from low server memory, then pm ondemand or dynamic maybe be better options. On the other hand, if you have the memory available you can avoid much of the PHP process manager (PM) overhead by setting pm static to the max capacity of your server. In other words, when you do the math, pm.static should be set to the max amount of PHP-FPM processes that can run without creating memory availability or cache pressure issues. Also, not so high as to overwhelm CPU(s) and have a pile of pending PHP-FPM operations.